# Where on disk does the macOS system-wide dictionary store the list of words I added?

Tags: macos, dictionary

I added a lot of words to the standard Mac OS X system-wide dictionary on a given machine, and would like to transfer that specific list of words to another machine. Where / in what file(s) is that list of words stored?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Are you certain you really mean system-wide? If I add a custom spelling, in Snow, it seems to end up here:

```
~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary
```

The System-wide equivalent, which is empty on my Mac, would be here:

```
/Library/Spelling/
```

Aside from this, you will find packaged dictionaries here:

```
/Library/Dictionaries/
~/Library/Dictionaries/
```

Comment: My computer shows a variant of this -- I have `~/Library/Spelling/en`.  This suggests that OS X will save dictionaries by ISO code for each language.

Comment: Seems to work for me. I copied everything under ~/Library/Spelling/. I had to logout/login again for the changes to be visible.

Comment: This answer no longer appears to be correct as os Mac OS Mojave 10.14 if not earlier. The local dictionary is in the same place, but /Library/Spelling and /Library/Dictionaries are gone AFAICT.

Comment: On Catalina+, this seems to contain the user's custom dictionary (i.e. the words that the user has added to the dictionary rather than a list of already-existing words). The other answer worked for me.

Answer (score 112):

For those attempting to find the Unix standard [words file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)), it's at `/usr/share/dict/words`.

Comment: What's that list used for? Are those words already in the standard OSX dictionary?

Comment: Lots of Unix utilities use it, since it's plain-text and easy to parse.

Comment: This also work on mac!